# What is the simple example of ajax synchronization?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read about synchronized ajax calls. It talks about setting `async:false` but how to get output to understand its behavior? Can you give me a simple example?

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated, and will sooner or later be removed. No need to learn how it works.

Comment: there is something in javascript called "async /await" functions , have a look at them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple. After this line of code executed, the value in `result` variable have content immediately.

```
var result = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: remote_url,
    async: false
}).responseText;
```